# Form with two/multiple columns and labels above inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that uses Bootstrap 3.  I use the native VS 2015 tool to auto-generate my views which look like so:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Label1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Text1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Label2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            Text2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

- Get the form to use two columns.  I am sure all I have to do here is use `col-md-x` so long as `x` sums to 12
- Put the labels above the inputs much in the same way they appear when I reduce my browser width

Here's how they look when browser is maximized:

```
Label1          Text1
Label2          Text2
```

I want them to look like this regardless of viewport width:

```
Label1                Label2
Text1                 Text2

Label3                Label4
Text3                 Text4
```

**Update**

Using answerer's example, I was able to achieve what I want by

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
            <div>
                Text1
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Label2</label>
            <div>
                Text2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Label3</label>
            <div>
                Text3
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Label4</label>
            <div>
                Text4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made your markup more complex than it could be. You don't need to set `form-horizontal` at all, just replace that div with `form` tag. And remove col-md-* classes, so they will fit whole width of viewport. You can define `class="well"` to `form` to make it pretty looking.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
          <div>
            Text1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Label2</label>
          <div>
            Text2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Label3</label>
          <div>
            Text3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Label4</label>
          <div>
            Text4
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my visual example.  See update where I update my second example to show two columns.  I seem to have been able to get it to work using your example, but had to wrap each group of items in a `<div class="col-md-6">`.  Let me know if there's a better way

Comment: I've changed the answer.